# Azure DevOps: Error when linking to wiki page from a work item

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to link a wiki page to a work item, but every time I do this, the link on the work item shows as an error that says, "Page may have been renamed or deleted." I've checked that the page exists. How can I get the link to work?

[image: wiki page error message]

Comment: I think this is more a ticket for the Azure DevOps Support (MS Support). We dont know your Azure DevOps configurations, linkings, wiki etc.

Comment: @Martin I think you're right.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure DevOps: Error when linking to wiki page from a work item

I used to have a similar issue when I first linked a wiki page from a work item:

`Work item`->`Links tab`->`Add link`->`Add wiki page`

To resolve this issue, please try to go to the wiki page, select the wiki page add click on expansion options, select **Link work items**:

[image]

Then, we could see the link of the wiki page on the work item.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried linking the wiki page to the work item both ways (from wiki page and from work item). Both ways result in the same error.